# Is it possible to read from multiple databases?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

as the title says: In MS access, is it possible to read from more than one database files?

I was thinking something like:

```
SELECT a.tbl1, b.tbl2
FROM tbl1, tabl2 IN C:\data\abc.mdb OR C:\data\def.mdb
```

Clearly this isn't the solution, but any advice or lead would be help.

Thanks!

Comment: Your best bet is to use a "Link Table". https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-another-Access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6 After adding a link table the table from the other database will appear as if it is a table in the current database.

Answer (score 1):

Access SQL does not support a construct like `SELECT ... FROM tablename IN file1 OR file2`. However, it *is* possible for a query run from within Microsoft Access itself to "read from multiple databases" like so:

```
SELECT d.DonorID, d.Amount, dt.DonationTypeDescription
FROM 
    Donations d 
    INNER JOIN
    [C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb].DonationTypes dt
        ON dt.DonationTypeCode = d.DonationType
```

(The table [Donations] is in the current database, while the table [DonationTypes] is in a different .mdb file.)